# Set user context in Spring Boot with JWT infos

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently working on resolving an issue related to setting the user context in the backend. The current application comprises a frontend (Angular 16), backend (Spring Boot 3.1), and PostgreSQL (version 15).

The workflow is as follows:

```
1. Users log in to the frontend and receive a JWT from Microsoft EntraId.
2. The JWT contains all necessary information, such as the user's email and ID.
3. When a request is sent to the backend, the token is included and validated.
```

The part I'm currently struggling with is logging in the user via the JWT. Steps 4 and onwards would involve the following:

```
4. Checking the ID or email from the JWT.
5. Retrieving the user from the database using the ID or email (we store all users with additional information in the PostgreSQL database) and setting them as the context.
6. Verifying whether the user has the necessary roles, for example, to perform the request.
```

Steps 4 through 6 have been a puzzle for me so far. I've attempted to work with a filter and set the user through the UserDetails service, but during debugging, I noticed that it's not being called.

Created Filter
Created a UserDetailService und overrided the function to find the correct user from the database

Some code, maybe it helps:

```java
...
@Entity
@Table(schema = "stammdaten", name = "nutzer")
public class Nutzer { // USER

    /**
     * UUID die nicht automatisch erstellt wird, da sie in Azure erzeugt wird
     * ('objectId' in Azure)
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "nutzertyp")
    private Nutzertypen nutzertyp;

    ...
    /**
     * Email Adresse der Person
     */
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    ...
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        schema = "stammdaten",
        name = "nutzer_rollen",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nutzer_id", updatable = true),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rollen_id", updatable = true)
    )
    private List<Rollen> rollen = new ArrayList<>();

}

// UserDetailService
public class NutzerDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired
    private NutzerRepo nutzerRepo;

    @Override
    
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Nutzer nutzer = nutzerRepo.getNutzerByEmail(email);
        if(nutzer == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Nutzer nicht gefunden");
        }
        return new NutzerDetailsImp(nutzer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Handing out JWTs to browsers is called an implicit flow and is dangerous and deprecated, so why do you want to build an insecure not recommended authentication?

Comment: Hm, good question. But why is Microsoft giving me this option, when its dangerous? 
Any suggestions how to make it the "correct" way @Toerktumlare ?

Comment: it very hard to make any suggestions when i have no idea of your requirements. I highly doubt that Microsoft is recommending that you should hand a out a JWT to a browser. Please link that recommendation

Comment: The recommendation was a missinformation by myself. The reccomend autorization code flow.
My requirement is to login the user with his microsoft account in the frontend (angular). When the user calls the (spring boot) backend, it has to check if the user is valid and perfom some business logic or maybe some graph api calls (create a guest account in azure). Hope that helps @Toerktumlare and thanks in advance :)